# GROUP BY day but also show time on day

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have price-table with TIMESTAMPs and PRICE spanning over 3 years.
I would like GROUP these with MAXIMUM price per day but also show which time on the day the MAXIMUM price occured.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT Date(TIMESTAMP), MAX(PRICE)
    FROM history
    WHERE Currency = 'USD'
GROUP BY Date(TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY MAX(PRICE) DESC
```

Result:

[image: 1]

How can I GROUP by the DATE (YYYY-MM-DD) but also show the time on the day when the MAXIMUM price occured?
(The time is included in the TIMESTAMP)

Comment: Which RDBMS used?

Comment: I use an interactive tool which is connected to Snowflake

Comment: Just use `max(timestamp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CTE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html) in this challange:

```
WITH max_price AS (
    SELECT DATE(timestamp) max_price_date, MAX(price) max_price
    FROM history
    WHERE Currency = 'USD'
    GROUP BY Date(timestamp)
) 
SELECT * 
FROM max_price 
JOIN history ON history.price = max_price.max_price AND DATE(history.timestamp) = max_price_date
ORDER BY max_price DESC
```

[MySQL 8 fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/56852901d145d93cc1b1d28439dde425/)

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way to use window functions and you won't need cte or joining table twice:

```
select * from history
where Currency = 'USD'
qualify row_number() over (partition by date(TIMESTAMP) order by price desc) = 1
order by price desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If your database server supports it you can use the FIRST_VALUE function grouping first by the date (and currency), and ordering the rows within the group by decreasing price:

```
SELECT cast([TIMESTAMP] as date), MAX_PRICE_INDAY_REACHED_TIMESTAMP, MAX(PRICE)
FROM (
     select 
         [TIMESTAMP], PRICE, CURRENCY, 
         MAX_PRICE_INDAY_REACHED_TIMESTAMP=FIRST_VALUE([TIMESTAMP]) OVER (PARTITION BY  cast([TIMESTAMP] as date), Currency ORDER BY PRICE DESC)
     from history
     ) as h
WHERE Currency = 'USD'
GROUP BY cast([TIMESTAMP] as date), MAX_PRICE_INDAY_REACHED_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY MAX(PRICE) DESC
```